# Displaying paths or trails with many points in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

I had assumed that Google Maps would only partially display .kmz or .kml files containing paths/trails with too many points. However, while trying to upload and edit such a map, I inadvertently created a map-view in which all the points are displayed. Each waypoint contains only text information, and all markers appear the same. Unfortunately, I don't know how to create such a map again. Any ideas?

If the question of how to display full paths/trails has been solved elsewhere, I apologize, but I'd appreciate the link. Thanks.

- [Map created from a .kmz file with a limited number of points displayed](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=212170685639124329436.0004d281390742da412b0&msa=0),
- [Map created from a similar file with all points displayed](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=212170685639124329436.0004d275971dca86548f6&msa=0).

(I created the original .kml file in MyTracks, edited it, and saved it as a .kmz in Google Earth before uploading.)

Comment: It seems I must have registered a path/trail directly from my cellphone app, My Tracks, and this one came out with all points displayed and markers the same. I still don't know how to due this from my PC. but at least I have a workaround!